# Is there a class (similar to contentProvider) to interact with jdbc or other databases?

Tags: java, android, postgresql, android-contentprovider

I am currently using a `contentProvider` to work with my `SQLite` database in Android. At the same time, I am using an online `Postgresql` database.

I was wondering if there is a similar approach that I can use for interacting with my online database as I do with my local database.

My current approach to make it generic is to pass in a table name, so the code can work with different tables in my database and take specific actions, based on the table:

```
public static LinkedList<Value> sendToServer(String tableName, LinkedList<Value> values) {
    LinkedList<Values> successfullySentValues = new LinkedList<>();
    switch (tableName) {
        case "tableOne":
            //Do whatever needs to be done in case of tableOne
            //Add the Values that are successfully sent to the database to successfullySentValues
            break;
        case "tableTwo":
            //Do whatever needs to be done in case of tableTwo
            //Add the Values that are successfully sent to the database to successfullySentValues
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("UnsupportedTable: " + tableName);
    }
    return successfullySentValues;
}
```

Comment: you need to have webservice to make a call to the server for cummunication accordingly.

Comment: How to interact with my `postgresql` is not the question. I know how that part works. I am just looking for an elegant way to interact with it and use something similar to a `contentProvider`.